# JSON response get data

Tags: javascript, json, axios, openweathermap

```
const axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config({ path: './googlerequest/.env'});
API_key = process.env.API_KEY;
lat = 55
lon = 55

url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${API_key}`

axios.get(url)
.then((res) => {
    let data = (res.data)
    console.log(data)
}).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
```

{
cod: '200',
message: 0,
cnt: 40,
list: [
{
dt: 1669388400,
main: [Object],
weather: [Array],
clouds: [Object],
wind: [Object],
visibility: 231,
pop: 0.2,
snow: [Object],
sys: [Object],
dt_txt: '2022-11-25 15:00:00'
}
],
city: {
id: 582854,
name: 'Alekseyevka',
coord: { lat: 55, lon: 55 },
country: 'RU',
population: 3966,
timezone: 18000,
sunrise: 1669349428,
sunset: 1669377822
}
}

Im trying to get a json response from openweathermap using axios but I dont know how to get data from the [Object] and [Array] part

Comment: can you please create code pen code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON.stringify() in your code at line 10.

Before

```
console.log(data)
```

After

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```